# FFmpeg child process closed, code null, signal SIGSEGV

Tags: node.js, heroku, ffmpeg

I have been working on a project where I am trying to get users' audio and video and stream it to youtube live. I tested my code on my windows machine, and everything is working fine, but when I deploy my server code on Heroku, I get this error `FFmpeg child process closed, code null, signal SIGSEGV`.

I used https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git for Heroku buildpack.

**Code snippet:**

```
const inputSettings = ['-i', '-', '-v', 'error'];

const youtubeSettings = () => {
    
    return [
        // video codec config: low latency, adaptive bitrate
        '-c:v',
        'libx264',
        '-preset',
        'veryfast',
        '-tune',
        'zerolatency',
        '-g:v',
        '60',
  
        // audio codec config: sampling frequency (11025, 22050, 44100), bitrate 64 kbits
        '-c:a',
        'aac',
        '-strict',
        '-2',
        '-ar',
        '44100',
        '-b:a',
        '64k',
  
        //force to overwrite
        '-y',
  
        // used for audio sync
        '-use_wallclock_as_timestamps',
        '1',
        '-async',
        '1',
  
        '-f',
        'flv',
        youtubeURL,
      ]
    
}

const ffmpegInput = inputSettings.concat(youtubeSettings());


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`socket connected to ${socket.id}`)
    
    try{

    const ffmpg = child_process.spawn('ffmpeg',ffmpegInput)

    ffmpg.on('close', (code, signal) => {
        console.log(
          'FFmpeg child process closed, code ' + code + ', signal ' + signal
        );
        // ws.terminate()
      })

    ffmpg.stdin.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log('FFmpeg STDIN Error', e)
    })

    // FFmpeg outputs all of its messages to STDERR.  Let's log them to the console.
    ffmpg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('FFmpeg STDERR:', data.toString());
    })

    socket.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log('DATA', msg)
        ffmpg.stdin.write(msg);
    })

    // If the client disconnects, stop FFmpeg.
    socket.conn.on('close', (e) => {
        console.log('kill: SIGINT')
        ffmpg.kill('SIGINT')
    })
}
catch(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

**Heroku logs**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: The screenshot you've shared is not complete—there are almost certainly relevant lines above and below what you've shown, and you've even cut off values to the left and right. Please [edit] the _complete_ traceback into your question as a code block.